# How can I convert an onload promise into Async/Await

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following Typescript that I would like to use `async`/`await` on.  But I can't seem to sort it out in my head how to do this.

```
private getWorkbookFromFile2(excelFile: File): Promise<xlsx.IWorkBook> {
    var loadedPromise = new Promise<xlsx.IWorkBook>((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
            var data = event.target.result;

            var workbook = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

            console.log(workbook.SheetNames);
            resolve(workbook);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(excelFile);
    });

    return loadedPromise;
}
```

Can someone show me how this Typescript promise can be converted to use `async`/`await`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> TypeScript now supports asynchronous functions for engines that have native support for ES6 generators, e.g. Node v4 and above. Asynchronous functions are prefixed with the async keyword; await suspends the execution until an asynchronous function return promise is fulfilled and unwraps the value from the Promise returned. - [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#toc68)

```
async function getWorkbookFromFile2(excelFile: File) {
    return new Promise<xlsx.IWorkBook>((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
            var data = event.target.result;

            var workbook = xlsx.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

            console.log(workbook.SheetNames);
            resolve(workbook);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(excelFile);
    });
}
```

Example consumption:

```
async function caller() {
    var workbook = await this.getWorkbookFromFile2(this.getFile());
    // The 'workbook' variable is an IWorkBook...
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to use await on the reader and the `onload`?

Comment: Nope, there is no need to as this is the lowest level of your asynchronous operation. The promise is that you'll return from this function when `onload` invokes `resolve`. Does that make sense? You're basically removing all the boilerplate code higher up the food-chain so to speak, such that callers of this function can simply `await` it instead of using the legacy chaining API.

Comment: @DavidPine maybe show an example of how this function can be used with `await` to make it a more complete example?

Comment: @DavidSherret, done -- thanks for the suggestion (and upvote)

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Comment: @Vaccano no problem, SO happy to help!

Comment: Greate solution! Based on this i wright similar solution to get uploaded img params
 `async function getImageParams(file: File) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var reader = new FileReader()

   reader.onload = async (e: any) => {
    var image = new Image()
    image.src = e.target.result
    await image.decode()

    resolve({ width: image.width, height: image.height })
   }
   reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
 }
 const { width, height } = await getImageParams(file)`