# Why await is not working for node request module?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-next

I'm new to nodejs. I’m not seeing the response in ex 1, but i see in ex 2. Why? Await works for me in other places, using babel.

Ex 1

```
 let res = await request(url)
 console.log(res);
 console.log(res.body);
```

Ex 2

```
request(url, function (error, res, body) {
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
 console.log(body) 
 }
});
```

Await works in other places, I’m using babel and required modules for es6 and es7 features. For example, await works in squelize call, i validated. But it doesn’t work for request call. Why?

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is not part of ES7. It's still only a proposal.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252603/2410379). Additionally, [this](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-definitions) is helpful too.

Answer (score 201):

You should only `await` on something that returns a Promise. I would definitely recommend reading up on Promises before you start working with `async` and `await`. You can probably get this example to work by creating your own wrapper function around `request` to make it return a promise, like so:

```
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        resolve(body);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Usage:
async function main() {
  try {
    let response = await doRequest(url);
    console.log(response); // `response` will be whatever you passed to `resolve()` at the top
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // `error` will be whatever you passed to `reject()` at the top
  }
}

main();
```

Edit: Alternatively, you can look into using [a promise-based request library](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143#issue-427486416) instead of the regular request module.

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: How about using `promisify` from `util`?

Comment: Really Helpful.

Comment: [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) has been deprecated since then

Comment: Thanks j-chan, I updated the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 26):

As @saadq says you can only 'await' functions returning Promise.

I like using Node.js's `util` package to promisify a function with callback. So `util` + `request` can be used like that:

```
const util = require('util')
const request = require("request");

const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);
const response = await requestPromise(url);
console.log('response', response.body);
```

Demo: https://runkit.com/mhmtztmr/node-js-request-with-async-await

Comment: This is just what I needed for a lambda -- simple and doesn't require anything other than Node

Answer (score 25):

**ES6**

**Usage:** Where `request` is `require('./await-request')`

```
const init = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await request({
            uri: 'statdirectory/exchange?json',
            baseUrl: 'https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/',
            json: true
        })
        console.log(result)
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
// await-request.js
const request = require('request')

module.exports = async (value) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(value, (error, response, data) => {
            if(error) reject(error)
            else resolve(data)
        })
    })
```

Comment: you mean async-request not  await-request? right? https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-request

Comment: @HMagdy no, `await-request` it's a filename of local file.

Comment: aha, yep got it

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following NPM package

[node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

```
          var url = "http://www.google.com";
          try 
          {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            return {message:json.message,status:json.type};
          }
          catch(error)
          {
            console.log(error);
          }
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

need to add await to the response.json() because response.json() is promise

```
( async function(){
      const{default:fetch} = await import('node-fetch');
      try {
        response = await fetch('https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population')  ;
        console.log(await response.json())
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Http error', err);
      }
    })()
```