# Proper request with async/await in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, rest, asynchronous, request, async-await

In my program I make `async` call for my function from another API module:

```
var info = await api.MyRequest(value);
```

**Module code:**

```
var request = require("request")

module.exports.MyRequest = async function MyRequest(value) {
    var options = {
        uri: "http://some_url",
        method: "GET",
        qs: {  // Query string like ?key=value&...
            key : value
        },
        json: true
    }

    try {
        var result = await request(options);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Execution returns immediately, however `result` and therefore `info` contains request object and request body - `info.body` like `key=value&...`, not required response body.

What I'm doing wrong? How to fix? What is proper `request` usage with `async`, or it only works correctly with promises like mentioned here: [Why await is not working for node request module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552394/630169)? Following article mentioned it is possible: [Mastering Async Await in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/).

Comment: `async` and `await` work in nodejs 7 latest build. so please make sure you have latest build of nodejs 7. For more infomation you can refer this link https://blog.risingstack.com/async-await-node-js-7-nightly

Comment: @Aabid I have Node.js 8.4

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You need to use the `request-promise` module, not the `request` module or `http.request()`.

`await` works on functions that return a promise, not on functions that return the `request` object and expect you to use callbacks or event listeners to know when things are done.

The `request-promise` module supports the same features as the `request` module, but asynchronous functions in it return promises so you can use either `.then()` or `await` with them rather than the callbacks that the `request` module expects.

So, install the [`request-promise` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) and then change this:

```
var request = require("request");
```

to this:

```
const request = require("request-promise");
```

Then, you can do:

```
var result = await request(options);
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like `request-promise` are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.

I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises, supports many of the same options as the `request()` module and is simple to program.

Newer versions of nodejs also have the `fetch()` interface built-in directly for making http requests and getting responses back (same API as fetch in the browser, but built into nodejs).

Comment: Why are you not saying that one can simply wrap nodejs' `http` methods in a promise like `return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)` ?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston - You can wrap anything you like - this answer at the time in 2017 offers the simplest way to add promise support to the `request` module (to just add 8 characters to one line of code to add the implementation that already fully wrapped it).  These days in 2023, it's kind of silly to write your own promise wrappers for making http requests.  We have `fetch()`, `got()`, `axios()`, etc... that all do this for you already and all have ground up implementations that use promises.  And, the `request` module is deprecated so nobody should be writing new code with it any more.

Comment: Simply use Nodejs `util.promisify` on the `http.request` method?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston - Why bother in 2023?  If you want promises, pick a library that natively supports them.  Also, `http.request()` is a LOT lower level than any of these other libraries.  The reason people used the `request` module in the first place is because it does all sorts of things that `http.request()` doesn't do.  `http.request()` doesn't read the response for you.  It just sends the request and gets you a response stream and you have to then read the stream yourself.  And, `http.request()` doesn't use the nodejs asynchronous calling convention that `util.promisify()` expects either.

Answer (score 33):

Pretty sure you can also do the following. If what you need does not return Promise by default you can provide it via new Promise method. Above answer is less verbose though.

```js
async function getBody(url) {
  const options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
  };

  // Return new promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    request.get(options, function(err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(body);
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of async here, when it also work fine without the async keyword? Pardon me with these question.

Comment: You can do this, and it will work, but it becomes very difficult to unit test `function getBody(url)`. I just learned the hard way!

Comment: as for me this is the best answer

Comment: Thanks @user3520261 your answer solve my big issue.

Comment: The `async` keyword is completely optional here and in fact redundant as the function is already returning a promise

Answer (score 13):

I just managed to get it to work with **async/await**. I wrapped it inside a function `promisifiedRequest` to return a `promise` that runs the request `callback` and resolves or rejects it based on `error` and `response`.

```
const request = require('request');

const promisifiedRequest = function(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (response) {
        return resolve(response);
      }
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
};

(async function() {
  const options = {
    url: 'https://www.google.com',
    method: 'GET',
    gzip: true,
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36'
    }
  };

  let response = await promisifiedRequest(options);

  console.log(response.headers);
  console.log(response.body);
})();
```

Answer (score 11):

Since `request-promise` has been deprecated, here are other options that don't depend on the NPM `request` package. `got` has been mentioned already, but it depends on 11 other packages. [axios](https://www.npmjs.org/package/axios), in contrast, only has 1 dependency (for redirects). Everything else is natively implemented and built on top of the native NodeJS packages.

Here is the same example using `axios`:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
```

```js
const response = await axios.get(url)
const result = response.data
```

or, as a one-liner in JavaScript

```
const result = (await axios.get(url)).data
```

One-liner in TypeScript:

```js
const {data} = await axios.get(url)
```

Answer (score 7):

For simple cases where you don't need advanced features like cookies, following redirects and retrying, you can use native `http`/`https` module to make requests:

```js
const https = require('https')

async function fetch(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.get(url, { timeout: 1000 }, (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
        return reject(new Error(`HTTP status code ${res.statusCode}`))
      }

      const body = []
      res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
      res.on('end', () => {
        const resString = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
        resolve(resString)
      })
    })

    request.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err)
    })
    request.on('timeout', () => {
      request.destroy()
      reject(new Error('timed out'))
    })
  })
}

const res = await fetch('https://...')
```

Answer (score 1):

7 months later im here to let you know... The Request Method Has A Callback As The Second Parameter

The Data you want to return can be attached to the original request body JSON then accessed in the `next()` function.

```
async function incomingRequest(req, res, next) {
 
async function pR_callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
p_response = data
console.log('after_request', p_response);
req.body.confirmation = p_response
next()

return data

} else {
    console.log("rejected")
    const data = 'error'
      return data
}}

//-----------------------------------------
var p = await request(out, pR_callback)

}
```

Then the express route

```
app.all('/this_route', incomingRequest, async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send({pass: "true", confirmation: req.body.confirmation})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using NodeJS only, you have to promisify the http/https `.request` methods. Probably cleanest to create a module that does this then import it for use like:

#### req.mjs

```
import {request as httpSync} from 'node:http';
import {request as httpsSync} from 'node:https';

function http(options,body){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const req = httpSync(options, (res) => {
      var data = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({"body":data,"statusCode":res.statusCode,"headers":res.headers})
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });
    if(!isEmpty(body))(req.write(body));
    req.end();
  });
}

function https(options,body){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const req = httpsSync(options, (res) => {
      var data = '';
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => { data += chunk });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({"body":data,"statusCode":res.statusCode,"headers":res.headers})
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
    });
    if(!isEmpty(body))(req.write(body));
    req.end();
  });
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) return false;
  return true;
}

export default {http,https};
```

#### myScript.mjs

```
import req from './req.mjs';


  try {
    let options = {
      hostname: 'www.cisco.com',
      port: 443,
      method: 'GET'
    };
    let res = await req.https(options);
    console.log(res.body,res.statusCode,JSON.stringify(res.headers);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```