# Nothing is executed after await

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I've hit a wall on my understanding of JS promises and event handlers.

I have an async function assigned to the FileReader's `onload` callback.
The code of the first asynchronous call executes fine (and if it throws exception, then the exception is caught). But the code after the first `await` never executes.

**Why does the code after await never execute?**

I expect that either the code after `await` executes eventually or an exception is thrown and caught by `catch`.

I'm trying to understand the reason the continuation is never called.

I'd also like to understand what is the best way I can call asynchronous functions from the functions that cannot be async. I understand that it might be impossible to synchronously wait for completion, but I'd like to at least trigger the asynchronous execution of **all** of the code.

```js
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onabort = () => console.log("file reading was aborted");
reader.onerror = () => console.log("file reading has failed");
reader.onload = async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Before");
    const digestToComponentTextDb = localForage.createInstance({
      name: "components",
      storeName: "some_store",
    });
    console.log("Middle");
    await digestToComponentTextDb.setItem("key", 'x'.repeat(20000));
    console.log('After');
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

"Before" and "Middle" are printed, but not "After".

**Update:**

It looks like one IndexedDB DB got corrupted in Chrome. I cannot view it. The "some_db" shows fine, but "components" does not show (it does not even gets selected). So The issue is apparrently with how `localForage` `setItem` handles writes to broken IndexedDB DBs.
[image]

Comment: Can you include your asyncFunc1 function as that is probably where the issue is

Comment: This issue is that a FileReader.onload function can't be async.  See [How can I convert an onload promise into Async/Await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252194/how-can-i-convert-an-onload-promise-into-async-await/38252603).  That thread has some code that seems to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Adam Fixed the `console.error` code. In any case, as indicated in my question, that part works properly.

Comment: @SethLutske As I mentioned, there are many other cases where the callback function must be synchronous. With all due respect, I'm not asking for help with FileReader - I'm trying to understand JS Promises.

Comment: If the code after `await` is never executed it means that the promise is either never resolved and the `await` keeps waiting or the promise is rejected and the code flow jumps into the `catch`.

Comment: @RichardHpa I've included the code. You were right. For some reason on a particular IndexedDB DB `setItem` never finishes, but also never throws.

Comment: You are trying to `await` a call to `localForage.createInstance`...is that itself an async function?  A quick lookup of the docs seems like it is not, though I'm not as familiar with that package.  Trying to await a call to a function which itself is not async or a function is the problem.  It will change the flow of function calls.  Pretty great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53113299/12010984)

Comment: @jabaa So, my expectations were somewhat correct - the code after await should execute unless the exception is thrown or the async function gets stuck forever (never gets resolved). Is that correct?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hek2vx1f/) is an [mcve].

Comment: @SethLutske The localForage.createInstance call is not async and gets completed. The `setItem` apparently gets stuck.

Comment: I see. So, this is a bug in the localForage library and not a bug in my code. The same code works with different table name. I guess the particular IndexedDB got corrupted. Never seen that before.

Comment: The documentation for `setItem` is a bit confusing, but if its getting stuck there, then its either a problem within that package, or the way you're using it

Comment: Thank you, everyone. After I've restarted Chrome, the DB is browsable again and the code now works.